# Dynamic routes with static parts on express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to do a path for express like that catches this types of url:

```
/events/0.json
```

What I've tried is... (and It's not correct):

```
router.put('/events.json/:id.json', isLogged, events.update);
```

Is it possible to do it with express?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `/events/:id.json`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will catch the pattern x.json where x is 1 or more characters.

So /events/0.json will save '0' in req.params.id.  Note that id is string, not number.  You have to convert if you want that as a number to do number arithmetic or to put it in database as number/int type